# Would justice, punishment accomplishment and dharma establishment take place irrespective of which side Krishna fought for and which side won?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita

If you see some of my old questions, you might find that I just can't admit why Krishna should support Pandavas in Mahabharata.

It's a very big dilemma for me, for last 1 month.

So to clarify it, I want to ask it in a different manner.

According to Star Plus and BR Chopra Mahabharat, it is shown that Krishna considered Yuddhisthir betting Draupadi and Arjuna not stopping Yuddhisthir from betting was *adharma*. According to Krishna, the war was a must for **justice** (not sure whose justice), **punishment** to people who did *adharma* and to **establish *dharma*** again.

Let me explain it with an assumption:

**So suppose**, if Krishna would be on Kaurava side, say Duryodhana's chariot, and Kaurava would win the war, keeping Duryodhana, Dushasana, Bhishma and Drona alive and All 5 Pandavas dead, would it still be called **dharma yuddh**, would the **justice** be achieved, would **punishment** of *adharmis* considered accomplished and *dharma* would be **established**?

**PS:** I'm pretty sure that I'm just making an assumption, but at the same time I'm pretty sure that the question is not opinion based. I see the assumption fair enough. If anyone here have knowledge about the *dharma yuddh*, the **justice** and **punishment** being talked about and **establishment of *dharma***, this question can be answered easily :)

EDIT: Clearly not a duplicate. Answer to the question which claims to be original of this question, doesn't have points which I need answers for. The answer their clearly doesn't answer what I'm asking.

Comment: whichever side Krishna is, that side is Dharma. that is the definition of Dharma. Not the other way around, where people without jnana check whether Krishna is on the side of dharma or not.

Comment: @ram I can't believe something without reference.

Comment: If you're asking questions purely based on the plot of B.R Chopra and Star Plus Mahabharat, [movies.se] is the right place to ask about TV shows.

Comment: Whatever @Sarvabhouma but this question is not a duplicate. Very bad experience here.

Comment: @Vikas I didn't vote to close this question. If your question is closed as duplicate, you can edit your question to indicate why it is not a duplicate. (which you did). If there is no response, you can raise a meta discussion also.

Comment: "**So suppose, if Krishna would be on Kaurava side**" - this is a hypothetical question so will lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: @sv. It's not "**So suppose, if Krishna would be on Kaurava side**" It's "**So suppose, if Krishna would be on Kaurava side, say Duryodhana's chariot, and Kaurava would win the war, keeping Duryodhana, Dushasana, Bhishma and Drona alive and All 5 Pandavas dead, would it still be called dharma yuddh, would the justice be achieved, would punishment of adharmis considered accomplished and dharma would be established?**"

Comment: We cannot presume hypothesis here, I think. Then it becomes a platform for discussing plots for a novel/movie. As pointed out by a senior member  in respect of hypothetical question,  you may get opinion based answers, which is against the rules of the site. @Vikas

Comment: @Vikas See [Can we post mythologically hypothetical questions?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/443) -- answer is NO!!!

Comment: @srimannarayana k v I don't see a single reason the precise answer here would be *opinion based*. If somebody has good understanding about my question and Mahabharata, this is answerable.

Comment: @sv. just because it looks hypothetical, it *isn't*.

Comment: Think it in this way: Let's assume (again hypothetical), Duryodhana, Karna and Dussasan had not insulted Draupadi, instead respected her whole life, would Bhima ever wish to drink his blood? No. It's hypothetical, but answerable without varying opinions.

Comment: The intention is not to know *what would happen* if this had happened. Intention is to know requirement of the war.

Comment: Look at your title: "Would justice, punishment accomplishment and dharma establishment take place irrespective of which side Krishna fought for and which side won?" - **irrespective of which side Krishna fought for** - Krishna only fought on one side, this is a fact, so why do you want to know about a hypothetical scenario, that what would happen if Krishna supported Duryodhana?